# Error with extension method in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, extension-methods

I am trying to write extension methods in VB.NET

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module ExtensionMethods

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function FindByText(ByVal collection As ListItemCollection, text As String, comparisonType As StringComparison) As ListItem
        Dim result As ListItem = collection.OfType(Of ListItem)().FirstOrDefault(Function(s) s.Text.Equals(text, comparisonType))
        Return result
    End Function

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function FindByValue(ByVal collection As ListItemCollection, text As String, comparisonType As StringComparison) As ListItem
        Dim result As ListItem = collection.OfType(Of ListItem)().FirstOrDefault(Function(s) s.Value.Equals(text, comparisonType))
        Return result
    End Function

End Module
```

But I am getting this error.

> Class 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' cannot be indexed because
>   it has no default property

What could be wrong?

I am calling the code like this.

```
ddlSalesmanager.Items.FindByText(survey, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

P.S: I ported [this wonderful code from C#](http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/2010/07/15/dropdownlist-findbytext-problem/) to VB

Comment: Use `collection.Cast(Of ListItem)()` instead of `collection.OfType(Of ListItem)()` since all objects in a [`ListItemCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.aspx) are of type `ListItem` by nature.

Comment: Apart from taht, the error must be somewhere else, show us the code where you're using these extensions.

Comment: Your declaration for FindByText has different parameters than what you are using to call it?

Comment: i think the problem is that i want first parameter to be the item that needs to be extended and the second parameter is for the logical flow of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your code works, so the exception must be raised somewhere else(what is `survey`?).
2. Use `collection.Cast(Of ListItem)()` instead of `collection.OfType(Of ListItem)()` since all objects in a [`ListItemCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez4tsddk.aspx) are of type `ListItem` by nature.

Tested with

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DdlFoo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="FooSelected" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="Foo1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Foo2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Foo3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event-handler:

```
Dim foo2 = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList).Items.FindByText("FOO2", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
If Not foo2 Is Nothing Then
    ' your overloaded extension is called successfully
End If
```